# How realistic are procedural textures in sandbox?

Tags: rendering, procedural-generation, resolution

I'm working with Unreal and want to make a Minecraft-Style Block-Sandbox with HD-textures. Since at that resolution the repetitive pattern becomes too noticable, I'd like the game to generate the textures on the fly, based on coordinates, so the blocks have a seamless appearance, and distance to player, so further away blocks have a lower resolution. I'd love something between Rust and Grounded, Quality-wise, so it will include PBR, SSS, and height maps. I've got a fairly powerful PC, but since the CPU will have to constantly generate textures, which all would have to be stored inside the RAM, I was wondering how realistic something like that would be in the first place. And how I could save resources, things like reducing the quality in the shadows or so on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like your real question is "How can I create high-quality seamless and non-tiling materials for my voxels?" - try asking that, rather than asking whether the one potential solution you've thought of so far will work.

Comment: It's not so much a wether or not it will work, it's more so asking for a second opinion if it's feasable for a computer to run. If I had a NASA supercomputor, or whatever, I wouldn't have to ask this question, but I don't, so I've got to know the "limits".

Comment: Here I'm assuming "work" includes "perform adequately for this application's needs" ie. players should not need supercomputers to play your game. That's a good baseline assumption for all questions on GameDev.StackExchange.